# Is there a way to combine chrome arguments with user profile?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, webrtc, chromium, testcafe

I am trying to test around a webcam using fake stream, however, there is a check to see if the camera settings is allowed before it can work.

I am working with testcafe and my code is similar to what is below which doesn't work for the args (unless without the profile).

Using `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` and  `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture` works for stream, however the check for camera settings still fails. I tried using a user profile which works for the camera settings but not the chrome arguments. Does anyone know how I can combine these two to work ?

```
chrome:userProfile --start-fullscreen --allow-insecure-localhost --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture="/path/to/video.y4m" ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome can't apply CLI flags without creating a new browser instance and can't create a new browser instance if you have other Chrome instances that use the same profile.

If you want to use "chrome:userProfile" together with CLI flags, you can close all Chrome processes on your machine. Or you can create a dedicated directory for a temporary Chrome profile and use it in tests by specifying `chrome --user-data-dir=$TEMP_PROFILE_DIRECTORY` as a browser.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second option. It seems the first option may be best for CI testing, however I was able to use a new profile for the tests.